# Caustic of non-focal rays inside ellipse

Tags: geometry

Is there a caustic formed when multiple reflections occur in an ellipse for rays not passing through foci, or are they reflected randomly?

(Focal rays on multiple reflections settle into reflected regions around major axis of ellipse).

Comment: Yes, and it is conic sections, either hyperbolas or ellipses, haveing their faci common with the foci of the "elliptic billiard". See the works by Serge Tabachnikov

Comment: Thanks. Can there be a relation between old and new eccentricities and offset/ starting pedal distance?